# Issue in Content Port with ECL item

Tags: 2013, ecl, content-porter-2013

I am facing an issue at the time of content port when a component having an ECL item attached with it.

Export is working fine but when I am trying to import it is giving error for the ECL items.

Is there any way to resolve the issue ?

Comment: What kind of issue are you having, can you provide some more detail? Does Content Porter show any errors you can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go into some more detail regarding the actual problem you're facing - is it on the export or on the import? And what errors are you seeing?

I've ran into issues Content Porting components with links to ECL stub components, and the solution that we used was to export & import the ECL items prior to doing the rest of the Content Port (from the ECLs parent publication). The ECL stub components will have no dependencies so it should be a quick export & import depending on the number of items you're looking at.

I am not sure if anyone has found a more elegant solution, but it worked nicely for us.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Josh. I will try this one. If I face any further issue then I will let you know